# Sub Forms in JSF

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have a form that loaded the following entity :

```
@Entity
public class Person {
       @Column(name="personId")
       private String id;

       @OneToMany
       @JoinCOlumn(name="personId")
       private List<Contact> contacts;
}

@Entity
public class Contact {
       @Column(name="contactId")
       private Long id;

       @Column(name="test")
       private String test;

       @Column(name="name")
       private String name;

       @OneToOne
       @JoinColumn(name="personId")
       private Person person;
}
```

I need for in one form in JSF can add and remove contacts, but in same Person form. I tried everything that was site and documentation but have not found how to do this.

Comment: You should post what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

I have see solution, add call cascade = CascadeType.ALL in annotation @OneToMany.

For example:

```
@Entity
public class Person {
       @Column(name="personId")
       private String id;

       @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
       @JoinCOlumn(name="personId")
       private List<Contact> contacts;
}

@Entity
public class Contact {
       @Column(name="contactId")
       private Long id;

       @Column(name="test")
       private String test;

       @Column(name="name")
       private String name;

       @OneToOne
       @JoinColumn(name="personId")
       private Person person;
}
```

This solved problem, I can now add and remove itens for save.